# How to specify --downloads option?

Tags: wp-cli

I am trying to figure out how to create downloadable woocommerce products.  Trouble is syntax for the `--downloads` argument for `$ wp wc product create`.

It appears that the downloads argument should be one ore more objets having "id", "name", "file" specifications.  The toughest one to figure is "id".  I tried using the specs for a download file associated with another product.  Still get an `[]` empty value for that new product when I ask:

```
$ wp wc product list --fields=id,name,downloads 
$ wp wc product create --name="CLI Test Downloads" --type=simple  --regular_price=20 --downloadable=true --downloads=[{"id":"2d40862d-0044-4da6-bd87-0e94bf5531d6","name":"e-SIGNES-53no2.pdf","file":"https:\/\/ventardlab.info\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/01\/e-53no2.pdf"}]
```

I get no error message, just that product is created.  But when I check the new product in the WordPress dashboard, there are no download file included.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by myself after browsing other posts under [wp-cli](/questions/tagged/wp-cli) tag of Stack Overflow.

Solution is quite simple: enclose the `--downloads` value within single quotes.

For example `--downloads=' [ {  .... } ] '` with the appropriate syntax inside the `wp wc` object. Voilà!